# Google Chrome interprets CSS very wrong...?

Tags: css, google-chrome

So my I'm almost finished with my website, it looks fine with Firefox and even with IE 8!
But Chrome just messes it up.

Here is how it looks on FF:
[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img713/6414/firefoxtr.png]

And here on Chrome:
[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img600/9174/chromedv.png]

See how Crome resizes the first image, although it is exactly the same code as the picture below?

Here is the HTML-Code:

```
<table id="todo" class="subview_table web_coding_table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="image/preview_small/todo.jpg" alt="ToDo-App" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <h2>ToDo Webapplikation</h2>
        <p>Einfache Terminplaner-App zum Erstellen,
Bearbeiten und Löschen von Terminen</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="white_triangle">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>



<div id="todo_content" class="invisible_content web_coding_content">
 <p>Die ToDo-Webapplikation entstand als Semesterarbeit zusammen mit meiner     Teamkollegin ---. Die Herausforderung hierbei war die komplexe, klassenbasierte Programmierung mittels JavaScript. Die App speichert Termine cookiebasiert ab und kann daher auch lokal vom Rechner aus verwendet werden.</p>
 <a href="http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~cr/todo_app/" target="_blank" title:"ToDo-App"><img src="image/preview_big/todo.jpg" alt="ToDo Screenshot"/></a>
 <a class="big_link" href="http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~cr/todo_app/" target="_blank" title:"ToDo-App">Zur Live-Demo</a>
```

```
<table id="resi" class="subview_table web_coding_table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="image/preview_small/resi.jpg" alt="Resi bringt Bier" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <h2>Resi Bringt Bier</h2>
        <p>Getränke-Nachtlieferservice in München mit Shopsystem.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="white_triangle">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div id="resi_content" class="invisible_content web_coding_content">
 <p>HINWEIS!: Der Kunde dieses Projekts arbeitet selbst noch an der Website und den Inhalten weiter, daher entspricht das Erscheinungsbild möglicherweise nicht meiner eigentlichen Arbeit.</p><br />
 <p>Resi Bringt Bier ist eine Website für einen Nachtlieferanten in München. Sie wurde mit Wordpress umgesetzt und verwendet diverse Plugins sowie eine eigens kreierte Theme. Hinzu kommt die Verwendung eines eigenen JavaScript-Codes, sowie diverse Codeveränderungen in PHP.<p>
 <a href="http://www.resibringtbier.de" target="_blank" title:"Resi Bringt Bier"><img src="image/preview_big/resi.jpg" alt="Resi"/></a>
 <a class="big_link" href="http://www.resibringtbier.de" target="_blank" title:"Resi Bringt Bier">Zur Website</a>
</div>
```

Note thate the DIV's with the class "Invisible_content" aren't visible.

Here the CSS:

```
table h2 {
font-size:1.5em;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-style: normal;
}

table p {
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.subview_table {
height:120px;
position:relative;
margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
background-color:#961518;
}

.subview_table h2 {
margin-top:0px;
}

.subview_table img {
padding:10px;
margin:0px;
}

.subview_table td {
min-width:70px;
}

.white_triangle {
position:absolute;
top:60px;
right:20px;
height:0;
width:0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px;
}

.invisible_content {
display:none;
padding: 20px;
background-color:#d8d5c6;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How unexpected to blame the browser. ;-)

Comment: Did you run your page through http://validator.w3.org/ and fix all issues yet?

Comment: This is the reason I avoid using tables for layout. It always ends up in disaster.  I recommend to use divs instead.

Comment: Try using a good css reset. That may solve your problem. Css resets can solve most of the cross browser issues. For your convenience here is one popular one  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: @Sparky : Only issue is a missing alt-Tag on some picture...

Comment: That's not true.  The code you posted above is missing a `</div>` tag and every instance of `title:` should be `title=`.

Comment: @GeekyCoder, how exactly is a CSS Reset going to fix problems caused by invalid HTML? Once you understand and fix all the root problems, you wouldn't need a shotgun approach, which in this instance, would have failed anyway.

Comment: @Sparky That's y i said "IT MAY SOLVE" not that it will solve..... if i wanted to say "it will solve"  i would had posted that as a answer and not as a comment.

Comment: @GeekyCoder I implemented the reset, still no change... but thanks!

Comment: Did you follow my answer?  It's working in this jsFiddle in Chrome now:  http://jsfiddle.net/t2cFb/

Comment: @Sparky : Thank you, but i just forgot to copy it on the page. It's there in the actual code. Sorry! And I fixed the title:-problem now, but i can't really validate the page because the HTML is loaded via JavaScript...

Comment: Yes you can.  Browser -> View Source -> Select All -> Copy & Paste into W3C Validator tab called "validate by direct input": http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input.

Comment: @Sparky: Thanks so far! "This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!" Still the error occurs...

Comment: Which error?  The overlapping text or the image size issue?  I'm seeing absolutely nothing in your HTML or CSS that tells the browser what size the image should be rendered, nor can we see the actual native size.

Comment: Are you also saying this jsFiddle is not working in Chrome now?  http://jsfiddle.net/t2cFb/

Comment: Both errors. The img's aren't resized. the fiddle also looks buggy on my Chrome as well as on Chrome on another Notebook...

Comment: Specify an image size in HTML, CSS, or both  http://jsfiddle.net/t2cFb/1/

Comment: Sittl no change... :/

Comment: Everything is really screwy here, besides the various inconsistencies of sizes due to missing CSS rules.  I'm showing you jsFiddles that I have working in Chrome and you simply say "no change"?

Comment: The problem lies somewhere in the middle <td>, because when I erase this td (the one with the text), everything looks fine... maybe it has something to do with screen sizes and that's why it works on your PC, but not on mine?? Idk...

Comment: Nothing to do with screen size.  See the screenshot I added to my answer.  The text is not overlapping the images and the images are the same size.  You need to carefully examine and reevaluate your CSS techniques... it's lacking **many** sizing specifications.  `tables` can be unpredictable when you just leave them to figure themselves out.

Comment: In other words, go back and specify `width` on your `td` elements using HTML and/or CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky, you were a really great help! I appreciate it! I now styled every single td with a specific width and it's working fine. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OP's Title:  Google Chrome interprets CSS very wrong...?**

Wrong assumption.  If your code is not following proper standards, the browser is forced to simply make guesses about your intentions.  In other words, you have invalid and malformed code which is the true root cause, not Chrome.

- Note that you have `<a href="http://www.resibringtbier.de" target="_blank" title:"Resi Bringt Bier">`, where `title:"Resi Bringt Bier"` is invalid HTML.  Should be `title="Resi Bringt Bier"`.  You've repeated this same mistake about five or six times.
- You *may* have also forgotten the closing tag, `</div>` on your `<div id="todo_content"`.  (depends on which version of the OP you're looking at.)
- Regarding your image size complaint: I'm seeing absolutely nothing in your HTML or CSS that tells the browser what size the image should be rendered, nor can we see the actual native size.
- You have a `div` inside a `td` cell, which is not a very good practice.
- Carefully examine and evaluate your CSS techniques... it's lacking many sizing specifications. `tables` can be somewhat unpredictable when you just leave them to figure themselves out.  Specify the `width` of each `td` in HTML and/or CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/t2cFb/2/

---

Run the HTML through the W3C online validator and fix all errors.

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: "Google Chrome interprets CSS very wrong…?" Just to back up @Sparky here, it's the wrong attitude to take when you run into a bug. Assume it's your fault, frankly. Firefox and Chrome are merely taking different guesses at how to interpret your incorrect code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fixed the "title:"-mistake. But where is the </div>-Tag missing? I checked 3 times... I see it right at the end of <div id="todo_content">... ?

Comment: @Kweamod, the `</div>` is missing from your original question.  Somebody edited it and improperly added it there when they cleaned it up.   I rolled it back to your original posted version.  See history:  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15719803/revisions

Comment: @EduardoReis , asking code questions within comments is not allowed.   Post a new question instead.